# Numpy operation in Eigen - Slicing

Tags: eigen

```
velodata_cam = velodata_cam[velodata_cam[:, 2] >= 0.1]
```

I have this operation above. How can I do this cleanly in Eigen?

Comment: You can try something based on `std::remove_if` together with `velodata.rowwise().begin()`, `velodata.rowwise().end()` and some predicate.

Comment: i tried that its pretty slow. slower than numpy

Comment: i just ended up allocating the same amt of new memory, writing my own for loop with a condition, then removing the remaining rows/columns. wish there was a nicer way to do this in eigen

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations enabled and debug-assertions disabled? This should not be slower than a manual loop: `auto end = std::remove_if(mat.rowwise().begin(), mat.rowwise().end(), [](auto const& x){return !(x[2] >= 0.1);});`

Comment: hmm didnt realize eigen had iterators